# Transform { key: [values] } to {value: [keys]} in rego

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

Please help me write a rule on **rego** that returns a transformed object.

My object:

```
{
  "read": [
    "server1",
    "server2"
  ],
  "write": [
    "server2",
    "server3"
  ],
  "create": [
    "server1",
    "server2",
    "server3"
  ]
}
```

Expected:

```
{
  "server1": [
    "read",
    "create"
  ],
  "server2": [
    "read",
    "write",
    "create"
  ],
  "server3": [
    "write",
    "create"
  ]
}
```

I understand that I need to use comprehensions, but I don't understand how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; you can use comprehensions to perform group-by operations. In this case, you want to group operations by server.

```
operations_by_server := {server: operations | 
  server := input[_][_]
  operations := {op |
    some op
    server == input[op][_]
  }
}
```

Here's an interactive version: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/y5ldvjvmfK

More info on comprehensions: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#comprehensions

As a side note, if you want to learn more about Rego, check out [this](https://academy.styra.com/courses/opa-rego) online course. Disclaimer: I work for the company that made the course.

Comment: Thank you. We are faced with some performance problem of such grouping. To speed up the grouping, we can first get unique servers. This can help with some data sets: unique_servers := {s | some s; input[_][s]}; server := unique_servers[_]